# Is it possible to run an obfs4proxy server and a webserver on the same port simultaneously, á la sslh?

Tags: obfsproxy, obfs4, ssl, obfs4proxy

[Sslh](https://www.rutschle.net/tech/sslh/README.html) is a protocol multiplexer that is commonly used to let one log in to a server via SSH on port 443, whilst that server still serves valid HTTPS content on port 443.

From its manual, it is described as:

> [Accepting] connections on specified ports, and forwards them further
> based on tests performed on the first data packet sent by the remote
> client.
>
> Probes for HTTP, TLS/SSL (including SNI and ALPN), SSH, OpenVPN, tinc,
> XMPP, SOCKS5, are implemented, and any other protocol that can be
> tested using a regular expression, can be recognised. A typical use
> case is to allow serving several services on port 443 (e.g. to connect
> to SSH from inside a corporate firewall, which almost never block port
> 443) while still serving HTTPS on that port.

It is my understanding that if one were to run an obfs4proxy server as a private bridge, it is possible to do this on port 443 easily. But as both apache/nginx/your webserver of choice and obs4proxy can't bind to the same port, an adversary who sniffed traffic, saw a relatively frequent number of connections to this particular website, and decided to visit it on port 443 wouldn't see a page -- and thus might become suspicious.

Is it possible to effectively multiplex the two, either by using sslh, or otherwise?